# Can I get MacOS or windows drivers runing on linux?

Tags: drivers

So I have a ESI ESP 1010 interface, not the 1010e (not the new one)
and only drivers for it are for windows and MacOS X.
And I want that interface to run on linux.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: well then it would be easier just to stick with windows, I wanted to use linux cause windows had a lot of problems with that interface, for example sometimes when I booted windows any audio player just wouldn't play anything at all, sometimes when opening programs the bit rate would mismatch for some reason. and I can't change the bitrate at all for some reason.

also wouldn't that introduce a lot latency?

Comment: https://fr.audiofanzine.com/carte-son-rack/esi/ESP1010/forums/t.196296,esp1010-linux,p.2.html

Comment: Someone at that forum said (I got this text using google translate):

Hello,

I don't have quite your configuration: I use this card under Kubuntu 8.04 32bits, with real-time kernel installed, jack and ardor, and no problem for recording / playback. I was also able to connect a MIDI pedal board to the rack to control SooperLooper, without problem.

Comment: thank's it seems there is some way to use it on linux, now just gotta find maybe some drivers or something

Comment: "Works very well on Linux, no need for drivers: no:
It's PCI: like: the ALSA drivers are only for those who do not pass with Jack, create a socket 10 E / 10 S ert it is gone, at boot choose the kernel without latency and it is only happiness !!! forget the paying meme steinberg you file the VST (2 line of cmd to compile or even)
"
I found this comment on that forum, it seems like it doesn't need any drivers. well I'll try installing Ubuntu Studio on my pc an try that.

Comment: They are talking about ubuntu studio. May be required drivers are built in into kernel of those distros or could be enabled by kernel recompilation.

Comment: well yeah I mean I'm gonna install ubuntu studio (distro) not like some program called studio

Comment: so it works, I haven't checked the latency yet, but it works without any extra software.
only problem really that it doesn't have any UI thus can't really do anything, only output I can use is the output 1, can't use headphone output sadly.
is there maybe some software that I can use for this?

Comment: https://community.ardour.org/download
Have you tried something like this?